# python pandas read_csv unable to read character double quoted twice

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm trying to a 2 columns csv file (error.csv) with semi-column separator which contains double quoted semi-columns:

```
col1;col2
2016-04-17_22:34:25.126;"Linux; Android"
2016-04-17_22:34:25.260;"{"g":2}iPhone; iPhone"
```

And I'm trying:

```
logs = pd.read_csv('error.csv', na_values="null", sep=';', 
                   quotechar='"', quoting=0)
```

I understand that the problem comes from having a double quoted "g" inside my double quotes in line 3 but I can't figure out how to deal with it. Any ideas ?

Comment: I would just let it parse with the double-quotes, and then manually strip them along the 2nd column. I think this is actually nicer and faster than preprocessing the file on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to pre-process the data so that it conforms to the expected CSV format. I doubt `pandas` will handle this just by changing a parameter or two.

If there are only two columns, and the first never contains a semi-colon, then you could split the lines on the first semi-colon:

```
records = []
with open('error.csv', 'r') as fh:
    # first row is a header
    header = next(fh).strip().split(';')

    for rec in fh:
        # split only on the first semi-colon
        date, dat = rec.strip().split(';', maxsplit=1)
        # assemble records, removing quotes from the second column
        records.append((date, dat.strip('"')))

# create a data frame
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_records(records, columns=header)
```

You will have to manually parse the dates yourself with the `datetime` module if you want the first column to contain proper dates and not strings.

Comment: To parse dates, if pandas inference does not work, use something like this: `pd.read_csv('error.csv', date_parser=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, ''%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S.%f")`. See [this table](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for the exact format.